# How to access native string formatting engine in browsers? (util.format for browser)

Tags: javascript, browser, format, native, string-formatting

I find it very convenient to use native printf-like formatting abilities of the console for printing. However, I could not find a way to format strings the same way to reuse them (without printing).
I'm aware of ES6 literal templates, and `util.format()` in `node.js`, but looking for a way to access and use the same native formatting abilities of the console in browsers, without inventing a wheel and adding external dependencies.

Say, we have code:

```js
const user1 = { name: "Mike", age: 42 };
const user2 = { name: "John", age: 24 };
const template = "Hi, %s! You are %d years old. Obj:";
```

Example 1:

```js
console.log(template, user1.name, user1.age, user1);
some_func1(???);
some_func2(???);
console.log(template, user2.name, user2.age, user2);
some_func1(???);
some_func2(???);

// Problem: only prints, cannot re-use formatted string
```

Example 2:

```js
let str_out;
str_out = "Hi ${user1.name}! You are ${user1.age} years old. Obj: ${JSON.stringify(user1)}";
console.log(str_out);
some_func1(str_out);
some_func2(str_out);
str_out =  "Hi ${user2.name}! You are ${user2.age} years old. Obj: ${JSON.stringify(user2)}";
console.log(str_out);
some_func1(str_out);
some_func2(str_out);

// Problem: very inconvenient, very bulky code, have to copy-paste and edit code (very bad practices)
```

Example 3:

```js
function sprintf(fmt, ...args) { return this.replace(...); }; // inventing a wheel
let str_out;
str_out = sprintf(template, user1.name, user1.age, user1);
console.log(str_out);
some_func1(str_out);
some_func2(str_out);
str_out = sprintf(template, user2.name, user2.age, user2);
console.log(str_out);
some_func1(str_out);
some_func2(str_out);

// Problem: have to use library or copy-paste code
```

So, the question is: **is it possible at all to access native printf-like string formatting abilities of the console for browsers?** At least at the moment.